# change and give id to values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have many **Dynamic** dictionary like this:
`{1: 'VDD', 2: 'VDD', 7: 'VDD', 0: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 6: 9, 13: 9, 'GND': 'GND', 15: 'GND', 12: 12}` 
I want to set ID as values for keys that they are not 'VDD' and 'GND' .
In this case the keys that have the same value must have the same ID .
IDs must start from 1 .

as you see I want Output like this:
`{1: 'VDD', 2: 'VDD', 7: 'VDD', 0: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 6: 2, 13: 2, 'GND': 'GND', 15: 'GND', 12: 3}`

I try this :

```
my_dict = {1: 'VDD', 2: 'VDD', 7: 'VDD', 0: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 6: 9, 13: 9, 'GND': 'GND', 15: 'GND', 12: 12}
i=1
for item in my_dict :
    if my_dict[item] != 'VDD':
        if my_dict[item] != 'GND':
            b = my_dict [item]
            my_dict[item] = i
            if b != :
                i+=1
```

but i cant figure out ...

Comment: You wrote "I want to set ID as values for keys that they are not 'VDD' and 'GND' " but your desired ouput also keeps key, value pairs where 'VDD' or 'GND' is the value. Can you specify that?

Answer (score 1):

```
def set_dict_keys():
    my_dict = {1: 'VDD', 2: 'VDD', 7: 'VDD', 0: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 6: 9, 13: 9, 'GND': 'GND', 15: 'GND', 12: 12}
    print(my_dict)
    output = {}
    mappings = {}
    current_value = 1
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        if value not in ['VDD', 'GND']:
            if value not in mappings:
                mappings[value] = current_value
                current_value += 1
            output[key] = mappings[value]
        else:
            output[key] = value
    print(output)

set_dict_keys()
```

The idea is to keep a mapping of values to IDs, then loop through all `my_dict` items and update the `output` dict.

Comment: Based on the discription of the desired output one should also check if key is in ['VDD', 'GND'].
However the example has no case where this would be relevant.

Comment: I presumed the integer values should be mapped to IDs, according to the output he asked for. Let's see what he replies.

Answer (score 1):

Using a *hacky* [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) :

```
from collections import defaultdict

genid = defaultdict(lambda: len(genid) + 1)

out = {
    k: v if v in ("VDD", "GND")
    else genid[v] for k, v in my_dict.items()
}
```

Output (*before/after*) :

```
{                    #    {
    "1": "VDD",      #        "1": "VDD",   # < unchanged
    "2": "VDD",      #        "2": "VDD",   # < unchanged
    "7": "VDD",      #        "7": "VDD",   # < unchanged
    "0": 0,          #        "0": 1,       # < updated : grp1
    "3": 0,          #        "3": 1,       # < updated : grp1
    "4": 0,          #        "4": 1,       # < updated : grp1
    "6": 9,          #        "6": 2,       # < updated : grp2
    "13": 9,         #        "13": 2,      # < updated : grp2
    "GND": "GND",    #        "GND": "GND", # < unchanged
    "15": "GND",     #        "15": "GND",  # < unchanged
    "12": 12         #        "12": 3       # < updated : grp3
}                    #    }
```